# Error al ejecutar npm install para activar ui-auth , laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, vue.js, npm, homestead

Estoy estudiando Laravel y monté un Homestead v10.8.1  en virtualbox, en Laravel 7 ya no está la configuración de ui-auth, entonces seguí los pasos nuevos para descargar ese módulo, el último paso es ejecutar `npm i` para instalar las librerias de vue y bootstrap. En éste punto se genera el siguiente fallo.

[image: fallo al ejecutar npm i]

En otros foros leí que tocaba actualizar el laravel-mix en el package.json , lo hice y no funcionó, después leí que ejecutar `npm cache clean` tampoco funcionó. ¿Qué otra cosa puede ser?, ¿alguien más ha usado esa versión de homestead sin problemas?

al revisar la carpeta views se creó la carpeta auth, con sus archivos y en resources/js , app.js y boostrap.js , pero es claro que hubo una falla en el proceso, y no funciona lo esperado.
Gracias.

Comment: Intenta borrar `node_modules` y volver a correr `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Prueba con ese comando